# Connecting to a Vertica DB with PHP

Tags: php, vertica

Is there a way to connect to a Vertica database with PHP -- a function similar to mysql_connect()?

I'm ultimately trying to write a script that pulls data from a Vertica database and stores it in a localhost MySQL database.

If necessary, I would be willing to work with Python to make this happen.

Comment: Once the ODBC driver is set up, the function, [odbc_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP ODBC module ([classic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php)) works fine for Vertica connections. You'll need to download the appropriate ODBC driver for your Vertica version from the My Vertica portal and install it on your PHP server.

Comment: I got a problem with PDO ODBC when using Prepared Statements and I needed to use the classic ODBC module instead of PDO ODBC in order to move forward: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65952&edit=3

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use a `Postgres` client libraries to connect to Vertica instance.

Comment: hello. Please, can you provice more details about using Postgres libs to connect Vertica and what exactly libs are required to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Basically vertica is a fork of postgres database. They've added their own storage engine etc etc. However the communicating protocol remains almost unchanged, so you can try to use any available pg client. Most likely it'll work.